# Drupal 8.6 how to disable HTTPS

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm having issues on a Drupal 8.6 multisite installation. So to debug them I downloaded a full backup from a cPanel and I'm running it using XAMPP on Windows 10. I pointed out all the website addresses to 127.0.0.1 using the `hosts` file.

The website is working but via `HTTPS`, which give me a lot of problems loading the admin. So I would like to make the website run on my local on `HTTP`.

I tried commenting this line in the .htaccess:

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And uncomment these:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
```

Didn't work. I also saw in Drupal's forum about the `variable` table in the database. This table doesn't exist in my databases. I'm not a Drupal dev (just trying to fix the issue) so I don't actually know if it should exist.

I also saw about the `$conf['securepages_enable'] = 0`. This also doesn't exist in `settings.php` nor anywhere else.

In my `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.qc.ca 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Yes, I replaced the `htdocs` content with the content of the `public_html` from my backup. It solved some issues I was having.

What else can I try? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You say you didn't saw $conf['securepages_enable'] = 0. Did you try to add it to your settings.php? Also, try using this as htaccess : https://drupalabc.xyz/question/what-ideal-htaccess-file-drupal-8-website

Comment: Also vhosts files are important when using multisite setups, could you post this as well?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Just tried both, it didn't work =[

Comment: Yeah multisites are not easy to set up.. Can you post your vhost configuration or don't you have it?

Comment: Did you follow this guide btw? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multisite/drupal-8-multisite

Comment: @Wimanicesir I just added my vhosts config to the question

Answer (score 0):

It ended up that the problem was in my theme. I had to comment these lines:

```
if(!$request->isSecure() && strpos($host, '.test') === false){
    //header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);
    //header('Location: https://'.$host.$current_uri);
    //exit();
}
```

And in the `.htacess` I had to comment these

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```